# Replace negative values with positive values in R

Tags: r, vector, replace

I am doing a task for my online course, for which I have to replace all negative values in a vector with positive in two different ways. I have the following vector:

```
z <- seq(-3.5, 7, by=1.5)
```

The first way is with the `abs()` function:

```
z <- abs(z)
```

I am trying to think of a second way to do the same thing, maybe with a replace function or something alike. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Try `pmax(z, -z)`

Comment: z[idx <- z<0] = -z[idx]

Comment: Perhaps `sqrt(z^2)`

Comment: Worked! Very interesting approach.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fast:

```
z<-z*sign(z)
```

I like akrun's answer and it is computationally fast.  Here is a twist on it for trivial purposes:

```
z<--pmin(-z, z)
```

Comment: Did you test the second one?

Comment: Yes I certainly did.

Comment: I missed the minus sign. Putting in spaces would make the syntax more obvious.